# How to find ICCID of SIM in Android device?

Tags: android, adb

How to find ICCID of SIM in Android device connected to Linux PC using command?

I have connected my Android device with SIM to my Linux PC.
I want to know ICCID of SIM in Andorid phone.

I can get the ICCID using `getIccSerialNumber()` when used in Android Application. But I don't want to run Android App on a phone. Instead, I want to get the ICCID using my Linux PC only. i.e. Either by using `adb` command or running a C program in my PC.

How can I do it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about Android **usage** are prohibited on Stackoverflow.   The only Android questions permitted here are those about Application and System Development, and related Development Tools.

Answer (score 2):

To call `getIccSerialNumber()` do:

```
adb shell service call iphonesubinfo 11
```

Comment: I get an error that READ_PHONE_STATE permission is missing.

Answer (score 0):

adb shell dumpsys iphonesubinfo

Refer to the usage of service call command in here [adb shell dumpsys iphonesubinfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27002663/adb-shell-dumpsys-iphonesubinfo-not-working-since-android-5-0-lollipop/34362809#34362809)!