# How to get IMEI number with Kivy

Tags: python-2.7, kivy, imei

I am new to `python` and `kivy`. I want to get the IMEI and phone numbers from an Android device. I tried the code from [kivy/plyer/issues/107](https://github.com/kivy/plyer/issues/107) but I get Device_id not the IMEI number.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the post, it works only on phones which means that on tablet you'd get nothing. If you are looking for something like "anchor"/constant on your device, I'd recommend you `getprop ril.serialnumber` from shell that should work on both phones and tablets.

Otherwise, again with shell you can use [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27003016/5994041) and you can avoid using plyer or other packages if you don't work them and you want only the constant.

To call the command use: [`subprocess.check_output()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output)

**Edit:**

That's weird, in your comment it behaves like it needs a root access to that command. It should look like this: `subprocess.check_output(['getprop','ril.serialnumber'])[:-1]` or `subprocess.check_output(['service','call','iphonesubinfo','1'])`

This [gist](https://gist.github.com/ktnr74/60ac7bcc2cd17b43f2cb) has python code to parse the `service call` command output.

Comment: thank you bro, cant you give me example code?because i got erorr OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied in adb logcat