# How can I get the IMEI on Lollipop and upper with ADB?

Tags: android, adb, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm trying to get the IMEI with this command "adb shell dumpsys iphonesubinfo" but is not working. Also I try this: adb shell service call iphonesubinfo 1 but neither

I did [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27002663/adb-shell-dumpsys-iphonesubinfo-not-working-since-android-5-0-lollipop) too but still is not working

How can I resolve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [adb shell dumpsys iphonesubinfo not working since Android 5.0 Lollipop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27002663/adb-shell-dumpsys-iphonesubinfo-not-working-since-android-5-0-lollipop)

Comment: `adb shell service call iphonesubinfo 1` [Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27003016/6809537)

Comment: I did that but it doesn't work because my smartphone is not rooted.
Result: Parcel(
  0x00000000: ffffffff 00000069 00650052 00750071 '....i...R.e.q.u.'
  0x00000010: 00720069 00730065 00520020 00410045 'i.r.e.s. .R.E.A.'
  0x00000020: 005f0044 00480050 004e004f 005f0045 'D._.P.H.O.N.E._.'
  0x00000030: 00540053 00540041 003a0045 004e0020 'S.T.A.T.E.:. .N.'
  ...

A kind of permission error

Answer (score 0):

Use below method to get IMEI simply..

```
public String getIMEI(Context context){
    String imei;
    TelephonyManager mngr = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    imei = mngr.getDeviceId();
    if(imei!=null)
          return imei;
    else
          return "00";
}
```

Don't forget to get permission in manifest fine as line blew..

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Comment: My problem is that I can't install app in those smartphones. So, I'd like to get the IMEI without install anything